# Application, files, video, music, docs doesn't show up after Ubuntu 20 upgrade

Tags: unity

I cannot find similar problem on askubuntu, so I will post a screenshot to show the issue since it's easier to show than to tell.

[image]

[Printscreen ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBF2M.png)

Comment: Screenshot clearly shows this is the Unity desktop, not the Gnome Shell desktop, so I updated the tag

Comment: Please clarify your release. Desktop and server releases use a *yy.mm* format for releases, *yy* being used only by snap based specialist releases (usually installed on appliances/devices or in the cloud, and usually used headless without screen/keyboard).

Comment: Desktop release

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal